# file system requires manual fsck on boot

Tags: filesystems, boot, initramfs, fsck, kiosk

Our company is providing customers with a digital signage Kiosk Machine that is running Customized Ubuntu 20.04. Our customers sometimes report that the Kiosk Machine is not booting because they land in the initramfs prompt where it says:

```
(Initramfs): /dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
  Inodes that were a part of a corrupted orphan linked lost found.
  /dev/sda1 : UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck manually.(I.e .,
  without -a or -p options). fsck exited with status code 4. The root
  filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
```

After doing a manual disk check the Kiosk Machine boots just fine. Can this has something to do with the Kiosk Machine not being shut down properly? Or maybe a disk failure? All the Kiosk Machines have the exact same hard disk and I know that our customers sometimes hard reset the Kiosk Machine which makes me think this is the reason for it. Can this be prevented when we do one fsck every day or once a week? Any advice on how to prevent this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Can this has something to do with the Kiosk Machine not being shut down properly?

Most likely.

> Or maybe a disk failure?

Very unlikely.

> Can this be prevented when we do one fsck every day or once a week?

You cannot run `fsck` on partitions mounted in read-write mode. If we're talking about modern distros, switching to read-only mode using standard features, without killing all the running processes or making them fail is near impossible.

> Any advice on how to prevent this would be appreciated.

If it's a true kiosk machine, find a way to have its disks being mounted in RO mode while the temporary data is being stored in RAM (`tmpfs`). There are tons of distros which allow to create live images with your desired settings and applications while not physically writing any data.